# Contact manager for Linux with good support for vCard version 4.0

Tags: contact-manager, vcard

I'm looking for a contact manager for Linux which has good support for vCard v4.0, meaning that it supports as many of the properties listed for v4.0 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#Properties) as possible.

I have a `.vcf` file exported from Nextcloud containing hundreds of contacts, many of which use properties like `BDAY`, `NOTE`, `ORG`, `PHOTO`, `PRODID`, `RELATED`, `TITLE` and `URL`.

The contact manager would need to support as many of these properties as possible, enabling their import, their editing and their export. I would hope for it to be a lightweight application if possible, i.e. I would like to avoid KDE solutions which tend to install a lot of other infrastructure beyond the basic application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/) + [CardBook](https://addons.thunderbird.net/thunderbird/addon/cardbook/) extension.

I can't test it with anything, but according to their [repository](https://gitlab.com/CardBook/CardBook), its features are:

> - Access to all [vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) data
> - Supports [vCard 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#vCard_3.0) and [vCard 4.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#vCard_4.0) (default)
> - [VCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) file export and import

It can also [run like a "standalone" app](https://gitlab.com/CardBook/CardBook#standalone).

Comment: What a good suggestion. With the small caveat that it doesn't appear to have the "standalone" functionality since Thunderbird 68 (we're currently on Thunderbird 115), this does appear to do the job. It's particularly good that it appears *not* to damage or seriously reformat existing entries and that it very simply modifies a VCF file in-place. And it appears to provide respectful support for vCard 3.0 and vCard 4.0. Thanks!